# How to access files and folders in a damaged hard disk?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

I have got a hard disk with problems. [HD Tune](http://www.hdtune.com/) shows a lot of bad blocks and CHKDSK fix it, but the disk isn't accessible via Windows Explorer. I will replace that disk, but I need recover some files first. I tested [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva), and happily it can see deleted files in the damaged disk. But it's my question, I didn't need deleted files, but the current files in "Users" folder. If Recuva can access deleted files, surely I can use another software to access the actual data. But I don't know that software I can use in that level.

Summary:

- I can view the HD via BIOS;
- I cannot access the HD via Windows Explorer, but it is list there;
- I can access the HD via [Piriform](http://www.piriform.com/) [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva);

I thank you for any help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a difference between physical corruption (bad blocks, surface errors, wear out due to age, etc) and logical errors, where the hardware is perfectly fine but the data structure to the files is damaged and the system can't read the files. Files deleted by accident can be considered to be in the second category.

Any data recovery software will be of use only in the second case. Nothing can help you if your HDD is physically damaged (well, there are some extreme measures, such as replacing the logical board, but it's stuff not to be done at home).

In your case, your seem to be having both physical and logical issues. I recommend you use Recuva (or another data recovery tool) to copy the files to a second, separate HD - remember, **never perform data recovery saving the files to the same HDD**.

As for your specific case, in order to use Recuva to recover files that weren't deleted but just unacessible, mark the "scan for non-deleted files" checkbox, see image below:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You may want to try a Linux distro in Live mode. Specifically, a ["Rescue Disk."](http://distrowatch.com/search.php?category=Rescue&origin=All&basedon=All&notbasedon=None&desktop=All&architecture=All&status=Active) Based on the brief descriptions there, [Plop Linux](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=plop) might be your best bet, but don't hesitate to try more than one.

Comment: If you use a Live CD / USB, remember to never save the recoverd files to the same HDD. **EVER**.

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy uhmm... it doesnt matter what you use to recover the files... you should never recover the files to the disk you got them from......... a Live Linux cd is the way to do it. http://livecdlist.com/

Comment: you would never want to install or run any application on a hd that is failing.... which is why you should use a Live Linux cd. Sometimes you will get only one chance to get the files you want. .. then bios will never see the drive again and you will never get the files.

Answer (score 5):

If you're willing to spend some money, you can pay a data recovery company to look at the hard drive for you.

Comment: Totally agree! 300€ in Europe for a normal HDD recovery within 2-3 days is the standard afaik (should be different in Southern America). Totally worth the money for business data, but for private stuff... I don't know.